# display title in each day in fullcalander.io

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, laravel-8, fullcalendar-3

i am trying to dispaly booked hotel room number in a calander. in date range the room number displayed in first date only. i need to dispaly the title(room_number) in every day it books.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var booking_details  = @json($booking_details);

    // console.log(booking_details);

    $("#calander").fullCalendar({
    events: booking_details,
    eventColor: '#FF0000'
    }); 
});
```

I got data by JSON

```
$booking_details = array();
$bookings = Booking::all();
   
foreach($bookings as $booking){

    $booking_details[]=[
        'title'=>$booking->room_number,
        'start'=>$booking->checkin_date,
        'end'=>$booking->checkout_date
    ];
}
```

Comment: It's one event, so it gets dispayed once. That's just how fullCalendar works. If you prefer, you can upgrade to a newer version of fullCalendar and then use the Recurring Events feature so you can display the booking as a series of recurring events across all the days of the booking. Then they will look separate and have the title and time displayed again on each day - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(booking_details);`?